# Running Mahout Application using AWS EC2 and Local Eclipse

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, amazon-ec2, mahout

I am trying to run Mahout based java project from eclipse. I have created AWS EC2 instance to run map reduce tasks and I am able to run example WordCount map-reduce task successfully on AWS EC2.

But now I am trying to write Mahout code using local Windows machine and local eclipse. But I am not able to understand how should I map my local machine eclipse code with AWS instance. I tried to google it. But there are not clear steps found on google. Could anyone please tell me steps for that. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

well, I'm not expert in AWS, but I do think that all your libraries (i.e. mahout including) should be installed on AWS and you are running it from your computer. You should not install mahout on your local computer but namenode in ASW (if you are trying to set up Hadoop map-reduce task).

Look at: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Mahout+Wiki#MahoutWiki-Installation%2FSetup

or:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Mahout+on+Amazon+EC2

Maybe I didn't fully get your question - if so, try to be more specific, what exactly didn't work for you....

Comment: Thank you xhudik for your response. I have already followed MahoutWiki steps to install Mahout on EC2. I have also check out all the Mahout core code in my local eclipse. But the problem is, I don't understand how to run code on AWS from LOCAL Eclipse. I have written wordcount code on AWS and tried to run it. That part is working. But now I have written wordcount code in local eclipse. But I am not sure how should i move my eclipse code to AWS in order to run it on AWS.

Comment: alian - try to be more specific - precisely: what guide did you follow? Which step didn't work for you?